# how to create customized edittextbox android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a customized edit `textbox`.
When getting a string of numbers I want to present them like this:

[image: Image 1]

Instead of the regular way like this:

[image: Image 2]

I have tried some ways but none of them gave me results like the pictures above, and i don't have any more ideas.

Do you have any idea how to create it simply?

Now i am using the button widget:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/licenceplatecontainer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/licenceplate_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/licenceplate_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:text="00-000-00"
    android:textSize="45sp" />
```

But the problem is that when I get the number from the user and setting the text:

```
Button btnLicencePlate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.licenceplatecontainer);
btnLicencePlate.setText(txtLicenceplate.getText().toString());
```

I am losing the pattern.

Comment: Search on _Google_

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried and explain what hasn't worked, then we can guide you. We are not a do it for you service

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice mask edittext for your need.

[MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText)

But maybe you need some modification on that EditText for looks it like TextView. For example use TextView styles for that component and make it unfocusable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default masking for edittext in android. Instead you can use the Custom class provided [here](http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-mask-with-edittext.html).

And simply use

```
    EditText phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);  
    phone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("(###) ###-##-##"))
```